# Is there a way with nearest neighbour search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE numbert_t ( v DOUBLE , id INTEGER, INDEX(v) )
```

and I want to do a query with a paremeter q that sorts the points in distance abs( q - v ). For example

```
 SELECT v, id, ABS( q - v ) AS d FROM number_t ORDER BY d
```

I tried the query above and this one:

```
 SELECT v, id, (v - q) AS d FROM numbers_t WHERE (v - q) > 0
 ORDER BY d
```

I also tried slight variations of the above:

```
 SELECT v, id, (v - q) AS d FROM numbers_t WHERE v > q ORDER BY v
```

They are not equivalent, but I don't mind to do two queries and have two independent cursors. However, in all cases EXPLAIN says that filesort, no indices would be used. Can I get MySQL to somehow use indices for this problem?

Comment: Can you post an example on sqlfriddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
SELECT MIN(v), id FROM number_t WHERE v >= q
UNION
SELECT MAX(v), id FROM number_t WHERE v < q
```

MySQL specific, not standard, because of the id. But the id might be retrieved *after* you have gotten exact values.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. EXPLAIN over your query says "using where", i.e., this effectively triggers the use of the index. Furthermore, I can use two queries and LIMIT: SELECT v, id, v - 0.4 AS d
FROM numbers_t WHERE v < 0.4 ORDER BY v LIMIT 10; I still get then "using where"... It doesn't work without the "LIMIT" part. That and two cursors will do it for an offline implementation of a locality sensitive hashing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spatial extension and a point datatype. Then you can use a proximity search for example when a point is inside a bounding box. You can also use my quadkey library. It uses a hilbert curve and a mercator projection. You can download my php class hilbert curve @ phpclasses.org.